# Column returning null values instead of values present

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query in which, I have merged a sub query for my requirement.

Here the query is.

```
select a.mkey, b.mkey RefMkey, a.doc_no, a.doc_date, 
            e.type_desc DocType, c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name CurrentUser,
        d.Type_desc Department, b.remarks, 
                (select f.type_desc from type_mst_a where f.Add_IInfo1
                 = b.NStatus_flag and f.type_code = 'S2') currentStatus
           from inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
        inner join inward_doc_tracking_trl b
            on a.mkey = b.ref_mkey
        inner join user_mst c
            on c.mkey = b.CUser_Id  
        inner join type_mst_a d
            on d.master_mkey = b.CDept_Id   
        inner join type_mst_a e
            on e.master_mkey = a.doc_type
        inner join type_mst_a f 
            on f.master_mkey = b.NStatus_flag
where a.mkey = 227394
```

but what happening here is, there are values present but I am getting as `NULL`

**Update**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inward_Doc_Tracking_Hdr](
[Mkey] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[FModule_ID] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[Comp_Mkey] [numeric](4, 0) NOT NULL,
[Branch_Mkey] [numeric](4, 0) NOT NULL,
[Tran_Type] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
[Tran_Code] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
[Tran_No] [numeric](4, 0) NOT NULL,
[Department_ID] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
[User_Id] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[Doc_Type] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[Doc_No] [varchar](30) NULL,
[Doc_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Dispatch_By] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[Status_Flag] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
[FA_Year] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[Party_Mkey] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[To_Department] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[To_User] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[Inward_Amt] [numeric](18, 3) NULL,
[Ref_No] [varchar](40) NULL,
[Ref_date] [datetime] NULL,
[U_DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[LastAction_DateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[Remarks] [varchar](255) NULL,
[Delete_Flag] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[Outward_Type] [char](1) NULL,
[Doc_Department] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[Party_Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
[Delivered_By] [varchar](30) NULL,
[Doc_Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Last_Department] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[Last_User] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[Approved_Amount] [float] NULL,
[Chq_No] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Chq_dated] [datetime] NULL,
[Chq_Bank] [varchar](40) NULL,
[Chq_Amount] [float] NULL,
[Vendor_MKey] [int] NULL,
[Vendor_Comp_Mkey] [int] NULL,
[Project_Mkey] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[Program_mkey] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[Payment_MKey] [int] NULL,
[Due_Date] [datetime] NULL,
[Updated_Remarks] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Updated_Bill_no] [varchar](27) NULL,
[Updated_Bill_Date] [datetime] NULL,
[Updated_Bill_Amt] [float] NULL,
[TotalDeductions] [float] NULL,
[Broker_Mkey] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[Customer_Mkey] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
[Payable_Amt] [float] NULL,
[Balance_Amt] [float] NULL,
[Req_Bill_Flag] [char](1) NULL,
[Po_No] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Receipt_No] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Bill_No] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Org_id] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Site_Id] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Site_Name] [varchar](150) NULL,
[Cumulative_Amt] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
[Email_Id] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Emp_Id] [varchar](6) NULL,
[Disp_through] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Disp_Through_Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Last_To_User] [numeric](10, 0) NULL
```

) ON [PRIMARY]

The query which shows there are result is

```
select type_desc, * from type_mst_a where type_code = 'S2'
```

Comment: Can you add table definitions and data for `mkey = 227394`?

Comment: how do you know there are values present?  Is there amother query that delivers those values?

Comment: @WalterMitty: yes, there is another query for that. I will update the query in question

Comment: @MilanTomeš: Check the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.mkey, 
    b.mkey AS RefMkey, 
    a.doc_no, 
    a.doc_date, 
    e.type_desc AS DocType, 
    c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name AS CurrentUser,
    d.Type_desc AS Department, 
    b.remarks, 
    docType.type_desc AS  currentStatus
FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
INNER JOIN inward_doc_tracking_trl b
    on a.mkey = b.ref_mkey
INNER JOIN user_mst c
    on c.mkey = b.CUser_Id  
INNER JOIN type_mst_a d
    on d.master_mkey = b.CDept_Id   
INNER JOIN type_mst_a e
    on e.master_mkey = a.doc_type
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT type_desc,
            Add_IInfo1 
        FROM type_mst_a
        WHERE type_code = 'S2'
    ) AS docType
    ON docType.Add_IInfo1 = b.NStatus_flag
WHERE a.mkey = 227394
```

Answer (score 0):

You not defined "f"

```
select f.type_desc from type_mst_a where f.Add_IInfo1
                 = b.NStatus_flag and f.type_code = 'S2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the sub query, you can do the same with the `join` itself:

```
select  a.mkey, b.mkey RefMkey, a.doc_no, a.doc_date, 
        e.type_desc DocType, c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name CurrentUser,
        d.Type_desc Department, b.remarks, f.type_desc AS currentStatus
from inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
inner join inward_doc_tracking_trl b
    on a.mkey = b.ref_mkey
inner join user_mst c
    on c.mkey = b.CUser_Id  
inner join type_mst_a d
    on d.master_mkey = b.CDept_Id   
inner join type_mst_a e
    on e.master_mkey = a.doc_type
inner join type_mst_a f 
    on f.master_mkey = b.NStatus_flag AND f.Add_IInfo1 = b.NStatus_flag AND f.type_code = 'S2'
where a.mkey = 227394
```

Comment: any suggestion on what's going wrong here ? i tried with left join too. but no result

Answer (score 0):

Your one of columns may be null,try left or full outer joins like this

```
select a.mkey, b.mkey RefMkey, a.doc_no, a.doc_date, 
            e.type_desc DocType, c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name CurrentUser,
        d.Type_desc Department, b.remarks, 
                (select f.type_desc from type_mst_a where f.Add_IInfo1
                 = b.NStatus_flag and f.type_code = 'S2') currentStatus
           from inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
        left join inward_doc_tracking_trl b
            on a.mkey = b.ref_mkey
        left join user_mst c
            on c.mkey = b.CUser_Id  
        left join type_mst_a d
            on d.master_mkey = b.CDept_Id   
        left join type_mst_a e
            on e.master_mkey = a.doc_type
        left join type_mst_a f 
            on f.master_mkey = b.NStatus_flag
where a.mkey = 227394
```

Comment: both joins giving me NULL only.

Comment: @stack try to add joins one by one, track after which join or sub-query problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

Your inner SELECT is what is known as a "correlated subquery".

Correlated subqueries can yield NULLS in the results even when there are no NULLS stored in the database.  If there are rows in the main query for which there are zero matching rows in the subquery, NULLS will appear in the results.

You'll have to do some detective work on your data to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
select a.mkey, b.mkey RefMkey, a.doc_no, a.doc_date, 
   e.type_desc DocType, c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name CurrentUser,
   d.Type_desc Department, b.remarks, 
   (select type_desc from type_mst_a where Add_IInfo1 = b.NStatus_flag and type_code = 'S2') currentStatus
from inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
inner join inward_doc_tracking_trl b
    on a.mkey = b.ref_mkey
inner join user_mst c
    on c.mkey = b.CUser_Id  
inner join type_mst_a d
    on d.master_mkey = b.CDept_Id   
inner join type_mst_a e
    on e.master_mkey = a.doc_type
inner join type_mst_a f 
    on f.master_mkey = b.NStatus_flag
where a.mkey = 227394
```

which can be rewritten as:

```
select a.mkey, b.mkey RefMkey, a.doc_no, a.doc_date, 
   e.type_desc DocType, c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name CurrentUser,
   d.Type_desc Department, b.remarks, g.type_desc as currentStatus
from inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
inner join inward_doc_tracking_trl b
    on a.mkey = b.ref_mkey
inner join user_mst c
    on c.mkey = b.CUser_Id  
inner join type_mst_a d
    on d.master_mkey = b.CDept_Id   
inner join type_mst_a e
    on e.master_mkey = a.doc_type
inner join type_mst_a f 
    on f.master_mkey = b.NStatus_flag
inner join type_mst_a g 
    on g.Add_IInfo1 = b.NStatus_flag and 
       g.type_code = 'S2'
where a.mkey = 227394
```